# Using .NET XmlSerializer for xml with different polymorphic roots

Tags: .net, xsd, xmlserializer, xsd.exe

I have XML docs with different roots coming from one source. I have a XSD schema just like described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950558/xml-and-xsd-use-element-name-as-replacement-of-xsitype-for-polymorphism), with the abstract='true' root element 'BaseElem' of a Base type, plus additional root elements Elem1, Elem2, ... that extend the Base type and use substitutionGroup='BaseElement' attribute.

xsd.exe generates BaseElem and the derived Elem1, Elem2, ... classes ok, with only the derived classes having the [XmlRootAttribute].

I would like to use the built-in XmlSerializer to both serialize and deserialize generated objects.

```
<Elem1>...</Elem1>  <!--This is the whole document, not a frament-->

    into this object, or in reverse:

var elem1 = new Elem1();
```

Serializing:

```
var srz = new XmlSerializer(typeof (BaseElem));
srz.Serialize(writer, elem1);
```

produces  elements.  To serialize with specific root, I must create serializer "new XmlSerializer(typeof(Elem1))".

Deserializing does not work at all if the BaseElem is used, and only works like this:

```
var srz = new XmlSerializer(typeof (Elem1));
var elem1 = (Elem1) srz.Deserialize(reader);
```

How can I have a more polymorphic, single serializer approach?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

if I understand correctly... could you use more of a generic approach? (showing just the deserialization snippet...)

```
   public static T DeserializeObject<T>(object obj)
    {
       XmlSerializer xs = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T));
       //etc
       return (T)xs.Deserialize(obj);
    }
```

Comment: i apologize for not completely understanding... your derived classes are using different xml root node names and you're like them them to be the same as the base class?

Comment: Yes, basically I was hoping for a schema that would produce a fake "parent" root for all different xmls i can get from the service.